# Text overflow errors in a bound list in html div

Tags: html, css

I have a set of bound classes inside a div and they appear as distinct objects one beside the other and the content inside the div is overflowing to the next line. I am looking for an approach which would be best suited to handle these text overflows. The two ideas I am contemplating on are:

1. Using tooltip- so when the mouse hovers on the div the extra content which is overflowing will be displayed and closes by default when the mouse moves away.
2. scrolling text- I am unsure about this one since like I said the objects are all bound classes and I am not listing them seperately so when I tried applying marquee to it all the headers of the different objects started scrolling as one long line.

This is how the code looks at present (does not contain the tooltip and scroll that I implemented since I reset the code to how it looks originally.

```
             <div class="BoundClass">    
                      <div>
                         <div style="white-space:normal"><%#Container.DataItem("cClassName")%></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

Could someone please help me with what would be the best approach to handle the text overflows and also the html, css code for it.

Comment: The best option is primarily opinion based, is your decision based on your actual UX / UI goals. Choose one try and we will help you to debug the code on specific problems

Comment: Could I get help with both-tooltip and marquee, I want to try them out to see which would be a better design on live.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle please? There is a button in the SO editor that lets you add one directly within your answer, so we can run the code right here.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I have an update. The following code is working for me, the class names are scrolling in their respective divs.

```
    <div class="BoundClass">    
                      <div>
                         <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"><%#Container.DataItem("cClassName")%></marquee>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

However I want to set a condition where the ONLY the text that overflows will scroll and the text which fits inside the div doesnt.

Comment: Is there any other way to handle text overflows apart from these two approaches?

Comment: Please read the notes with the red background here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: So which direction should I head in now, if not marquee? and I am sorry but where exactly is this jsfiddle?

Comment: Apparently they are called [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)